# tox cannot find the xml in my python package

Tags: python, python-poetry, tox, pyproject.toml

I am using tox together with pyproject.toml for my app. I have a config.xml under my package. My folder structure is exactly the same as https://github.com/trainindata/deploying-machine-learning-models/tree/master/section-05-production-model-package/regression_model except I do not have manifest.in and I am using pyproject.toml. My understanding is that pyproject.toml should be able to completely replace Manifest.in. However in the .tox file, my config.xml file is nowhere to be found. I wonder what I should do under this sitatuion.

Comment: You need to show your project.toml as it depends on the build system you use what needs to be done to include data files. toy isolates the build and what is not included in the build cannot be accessed

Comment: As much as possible you should present all pieces of the issue directly in the question (at the very least the relevent parts of the content of the files you mention). Even better with a [mre].